# Is IsActive in StoreLicense Class useable?

Tags: c#, uwp, in-app-purchase, add-on

Just wondering if anyone can help me out.

I implemented the following piece of code to check if the user has bought an add-on for my UWP app targeting the Creator's Update:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, StoreLicense> item in appLicense.AddOnLicenses)
{
    StoreLicense addOnLicense = item.Value;

    if (addOnLicense.IsActive)
    {
         Frame.Navigate(typeof(thispage));
    }

    else
    {
         var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("You need to buy the add-on to access this part of the app.");
         await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

However, IsActive always seemed to return true. When researching this on Microsoft docs, in the StoreLicense Class, I found out that the IsActive property is "reserved for future use, and it is not intended to be used in the current release. Currently, it always returns true." So if this is the case, how can I determine if the user has an active license for my add-on?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there's no need to check the value of `IsActive` property to see if the add-on license is valid, since `AddOnLicenses` dictionary only contains products for which the user has active license:

> **Remarks**
>
> This collection contains durable add-on licenses that are currently valid. When a license is expired or no longer valid, it will no longer be available in this collection.
>   [[`AddOnLicenses` property of `StoreAppLicense` class]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeapplicense#Windows_Services_Store_StoreAppLicense_AddOnLicenses)

So, simply checking if the add-on is in the collection should do the job.

Alternatively, you can check the value of `IsActive` property of the `ProductLicense` class (uses older `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store` namespace):

```
private bool IsLicenseActive(string productName)
{
    return CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[productName].IsActive);
}
```

Note that execution of this method may take a while in case of bad internet connection, so you're better off wrapping it in `Task` and waiting for the result asynchronously to avoid freezing the UI.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. Only thing is I was hoping to use the newer Windows.Services.Store namespace, instead of Windows.ApplicationModel.Store as it is no longer being updated. Is there any way to do use the newer namespace or is it better to use ApplicationModel.Store?

Comment: @hlbmallo I'm sorry, I completely forgot that the `CurrentApp` class was in the old namespace. `AddOnLicenses` dictionary only contains the AddOns that user is licensed to use. So there's no need to check the value of `IsActive` property: if the AddOn is in the dictionary, then user has bought it, and vice versa.

Comment: Hey @A. Milto, thought I had worked this out but I'm still struggling to implement the in-app purchase experience. I replaced the line 'if (addOnLicense.IsActive)' with 'if (addOnLicense.SkuStoreId == "MYSTOREID")' to check that the license for this particular add-on is in the user's collection, but when I do this my 'else' statement is run instead. Any ideas on how to overcome this? Cheers.

Comment: @hlbmallo Compare `MYSTOREID` with `InAppOfferToken`.

Comment: I gave this a go but still no joy unfortunately. From the docs it sounds like the productID is related to InAppOfferToken, and SkuStoreId is related to StoreID, but comparing these values doesn't seem to work. I've tried on multiple test accounts, some which have bought the add-on and others not. It keeps running the else statement.

Comment: @hlbmallo What values do `SkuStoreId` and `InAppOfferToken` contain? To see the values put a breakpoint on the line with the `if` statement (set the mouse cursor on the line and press F9), run the app in debug mode with debugger attached (press F5), and when it pauses, hover the cursor over these properties in code editor.

Comment: @hlbmallo Also try this: `if(appLicense.AddOnLicenses.Values.ContainsKey("MYSTOREID"))`

Comment: After debugging with the breakpoints, the values for the SkuStoreId and InAppOfferToken are my StoreID (with 4-digit SKU code at the end) and my productID respectively, both from the Dev Center Dashboard. This was really helpful because prior to doing this debugging, I hadn't realised that I needed to add the 4-digit SKU code to the end of the StoreId to get the SkuStoreId code (silly mistake by me!)

Comment: So now when I run the app with 'if (addOnLicense.SkuStoreId == "MYSTOREIDWITHSKUCODE")', the if statement is run. Which is great! Only thing is now there is a new problem: the if statement is run even when the user has no license, at least that's what's happening on my test PC/account.